How to create a dynamic VSTACK comprised of arrays formed with MAKEARRAY in Google Sheets
This is probably a simple one but it is eluding me somehow. We are a security company managing access control systems in multi-unit residential buildings.
I have a Google sheet that we give to our clients to fill out that comes back to us containing names of tenants in a building, their apt #, and a number of access control cards to be issued to each person.
From that, I need to generate another sheet that has a vstack with a row for each card to be issued so we can record the serial number of the cards and who they were issued to.
If the first sheet contains:



Name
Apartment
Value




Bob
Apt 2
5


Jill
Apt 5
2


Sam
Apt 1
0


George
Apt 7
1



Blanks or zeroes in the 3rd column should be ignored. The second sheet should look as so:



Name
Apartment




Bob
Apt 2


Bob
Apt 2


Bob
Apt 2


Bob
Apt 2


Bob
Apt 2


Jill
Apt 5


Jill
Apt 5


George
Apt 7



The formula needs to be dynamic so that the first sheet can contain as many or as few rows as needed for the particular building.
I have messed around with MAKEARRAY which does a fine job of producing an array from a single row in Sheet 1 but I was unable to figure out how to stack those arrays dynamically in Sheet 2 using VSTACK.

You can use REDUCE:
=ARRAYFORMULA(REDUCE(A1:B1,A2:INDEX(A:A,MATCH(,0/LEN(A:A))),LAMBDA(a,c,
   VSTACK(a,IFERROR(IF(SEQUENCE(OFFSET(c,,2)),{c,OFFSET(c,,1)}),TOCOL(,1))))))


You can also do this with string concatenation and SPLIT.
=ARRAYFORMULA(LET(v,TOCOL(C2:C,1),SPLIT(TOCOL(IF(
    SEQUENCE(1,MAX(v))>v,,TOCOL(A2:A,1)&"❄"&TOCOL(B2:B,1)),1),"❄")))




Here's one approach using makearray()
=let(Σ,C2:C, index(split(tocol(makearray(match(,0/(Σ<>"")),max(Σ),lambda(r,c,if(index(Σ,r)>=c,join("|",index(A2:B,r)),))),1),"|")))


